# How to delete a view programatically in D7?

Tags: views

How to delete a view programatically?

It's crazy I can't find proper answer for such a simple question.

Comment: [`views_view::delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/view::delete/7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Views has a function in it called views_delete_view, it takes a view object as a param. Try views_delete_view($yourloaded_view), that should do the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Give a try to the following code to delete the view:

```
// Check the view id the one that you are looking for.
if ($view = views_get_view($name)) {
  // Delete the view if it is the one that you are looking for.
  views_delete_view($view);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Anyone can explain why I have to use this syntax: $view->delete(); ? Above it there is views_delete_view($view) function already, which (as @Jance said) should do the trick.

Comment: You don't. Just use the first two lines, up to `views_delete_view`. This answer is way more elaborate than necessary: `views_delete_view` calls `$view->delete();` and then the `delete` method does the cache invalidation.

Comment: @chx Thanks for correcting. I have updated the answer.

@David Please ignore the `$view->delete();` , if required you may check the answer now.